# nuxt with vue-dragscroll: window is not defined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to use `vue-dragscroll` with `nuxtjs`.

I am new to `nuxtjs` and I have been using `vue-dragscroll` before with regular `vuejs`.

I have been shown an error **Window is not defined**, I've looked at the `vue-dragscroll` documentation and I still couldn't find the solution.

[image]

This is how I implemented the `vue-dragscroll`

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    CountriesSearch.mb-2
    div#countryList(v-for="country in countries" :key="country.country" v-dragscroll)
      CountryItem(:country="country" v-if="country.Country")
</template>

<script>
import { dragscroll } from 'vue-dragscroll'

export default {
  directives: {
    dragscroll
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to declare it as a directive within a `plugin` file.

```
// plugins/vue-dragscroll.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { dragscroll } from 'vue-dragscroll'

Vue.directive('dragscroll', dragscroll)
```

Then, in your `nuxt.config.js` add that plugin file to your `plugins: []` array:

```
{ src: '@/plugins/vue-dragscroll.js', ssr: false }
```

This directive leverages the `window` which is unavailable during SSR, hence your error.

Comment: Thank you it worked!. if I do it this way it will be registered as Global right? is there a way to register for single component use only?

Comment: @Evan Unfortunately this does pollute the global scope and doesn't have a work around offering. You could fork that repository and only load it if `window` is available.